# Sql request : select in a table depending on values in another table

Tags: sql, pdo, request

I'm trying a really tough select ... hope you can help me.

Here is the thing. [I have these two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/056wR.png)

I want to select in "students" everyone who do not have "unique_key" = :myvalue in the "attendance" table

For example :
with the value 3_2017-07-10, I want to select 2, 4, 5
with the value 3_2017-07-17, I want to select 3, 4

I tried with some LEFT JOIN, I tried with some NOT EXISTS... in vain.
I just cannot find a way to do it.

Any ideas ?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e4a515/1

```
Select * from students where id not in (Select id_eleve from attendance where unique_key='3_2017-07-10');
Select * from students where id not in (Select id_eleve from attendance where unique_key='3_2017-07-17');
```